# How to use promises in recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, es6-promise

I'm doing a task in which I have to implement analyze function.
The analyze function should gather information about a folder and its content. The function should return an object that will have the following format.

```
{
    totalFiles: number; // Contains total count of files in the folder and all its sub-folders.
    totalSubFolders: number; // Contains total count of subfolders in the folder and all its sub-folders.
    fileTypesInformation: FileTypeInformation[]; // Contains an array of FileTypeInformation objects that are described below.
}
```

The FileTypeInformation object type has the following format.

```
{
    fileExtension: string; // Contains file extension. This should be unique in the whole fileTypesInformation array.
    fileCount: number; // Contains total count of files with such extension in the folder and all its sub-folders.
}
```

> Create a file analyze.js that will export a function that implements
> expected behavior. The callback function passed to the analyze
> function should be called with the result object that has the format
> described in the beginning of the task. The first parameter of the
> callback will be an error object in case any occurred, the second
> parameter will be result. Keep in mind the node.js callback pattern.

This is code that checks this task:

```
const path = require('path');
const analyze = require('../src/analyze');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const testAssetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')

describe('analyze(folderPath, callback)', () => {
  it('should return an error in case a path to invalid folder was provided', async () => {
    const callbackStub = sinon.stub();
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      callbackStub.callsFake(() => resolve());
    });

    analyze('/unexistedfolderblab-blab', callbackStub);

    await promise;

    expect(callbackStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;

    const callArguments = callbackStub.getCall(0).args;
    expect(callArguments[0]).to.be.instanceOf(Error);
    expect(callArguments[1]).to.be.equal(undefined);
  });

  let result;
  const callbackStub = sinon.stub();

  before(async () => {
    result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      callbackStub.callsFake(() => {
        resolve();
      })

      analyze(testAssetsPath, callbackStub);
    });
  })

  it('should call callback function once', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  })

  it('should pass null as an error in case of a success', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[0]).to.be.equal(null);
  });

  it('should pass an object that has totalFiles number property', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1]).to.has.property('totalFiles');
    expect(typeof callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].totalFiles).to.be.equal('number');
  });

  it('should pass an object that has totalSubFolders number property', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1]).to.has.property('totalSubFolders');
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].totalSubFolders).to.be.an('number');
  });

  it('should pass an object that has fileTypesInformation array property', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1]).to.has.property('fileTypesInformation');
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].fileTypesInformation).to.be.instanceOf(Array);
  });

  it('should pass correct format of objects for fileTypesInformation array', () => {
    for (const fileTypeInfo of callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].fileTypesInformation) {
      expect(fileTypeInfo).to.has.all.keys('fileExtension', 'fileCount');
      expect(fileTypeInfo.fileExtension).to.be.an('string');
      expect(fileTypeInfo.fileCount).to.be.an('number');
    }
  });

  it('should pass correct totalFiles value', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].totalFiles).to.be.equal(10);
  });

  it('should pass correct totalSubFolders value', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].totalSubFolders).to.be.equal(4);
  });

  it('should pass fileTypesInformation array that has correct information about extension', () => {
    expect(callbackStub.getCall(0).args[1].fileTypesInformation).to.have.deep.members([
      {
        fileExtension: '.logs',
        fileCount: 1,
      },
      {
        fileExtension: '.errors',
        fileCount: 1,
      },
      {
        fileExtension: '.html',
        fileCount: 3,
      },
      {
        fileExtension: '.json',
        fileCount: 1,
      },
      {
        fileExtension: '.jpeg',
        fileCount: 2,
      },
      {
        fileExtension: '.css',
        fileCount: 2,
      }
    ],
      'It should has the following information about files: .logs - 1, .errors - 1, .html - 3, .json - 1, .jpeg - 2, .css - 2'
    );
  })
});
```

This was my implementation:

```
/**
 * @param folderPath: {String}
 * @param callback: {Function}
 */
const fs = require("fs");

class FileTypeInformation {
  constructor(fileExtension, fileCount) {
    this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    this.fileCount = fileCount;
  }
}

function analyze(folderPath, callback) {
  let result = {
    totalFiles: 0,
    totalSubFolders: 0,
    fileTypesInformation: []
  };

  function readDirectory(path) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      let fileCount = 0;
      let subFolderCount = 0;
      let fileTypeInformation = {};

      files.forEach((name) => {
        const filePath = `${path}/${name}`;
        const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);

        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
          subFolderCount++;
          readDirectory(filePath);
        } else {
          fileCount++;
          const fileExtension = `.${name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase()}`;
          fileTypeInformation[fileExtension] =
            (fileTypeInformation[fileExtension] || 0) + 1;
        }
      });

      result.totalFiles += fileCount;
      result.totalSubFolders += subFolderCount;

      Object.entries(fileTypeInformation).forEach(([fileExtension, fileCount]) => {
        const fileType = new FileTypeInformation(fileExtension, fileCount);
        result.fileTypesInformation.push(fileType);
      });

      
    });

  }

  readDirectory(folderPath);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.fileTypesInformation.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < result.fileTypesInformation.length; j++) {
            if(result.fileTypesInformation[i].fileExtension === result.fileTypesInformation[j].fileExtension && i !== j){
                result.fileTypesInformation[i].fileCount += result.fileTypesInformation[j].fileCount;
                result.fileTypesInformation.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
      }
    callback(null,result);
  }, 4000);
}

module.exports = analyze;
```

Failure message:

> Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()"
> is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
> (/tmp/builds/autocode_11661/test/analyze.js)

I think It should be solved with promises but I am not sure how to implement promises in recursive functions, I can show my implementation with promises also but it does not work as intended.

Comment: After a quick skim, it looks like your analysis method waits 4 seconds and calls the callback, and the error is that it the test is taking too long (2 seconds).  What happens if you set the test timeout to, say, 5 seconds?

Comment: I am not allowed to change anything in this tester code, also I don't even know how to do that (I don't see variable or value that is responsible for that)

Comment: @solvera do you know what this code does: `setTimeout(() => {
    /* .... */
    callback(null,result);
  }, 4000);`

Comment: @NathanChappell It waits for 4 seconds before calling callback function

Comment: @Sovera why the timeout? what do you wait for? why 4 seconds? why not 2, or 10?

Comment: I tested 4 seconds and it worked perfectly, I don't know how to use promises so only way I found to get correct result from asynchronous function was this, don't mind that setTimeout if you can help with this task it would be appreciated @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tests must complete in 2 seconds and you have implemented a delay 4 seconds before calling the callback, it should come as no surprise that you get a timeout error.

Instead you should call the callback as soon as you have the result ready. It is probably easiest to use a promise-enabled library.

The `fs` library which use use [has promise enabled equivalents](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system):

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';
```

Then `readdir` returns a promise. Your function can then change to an `async` function, using `await` and `Promise.all`

```
  async function readDirectory(path) {
    const files = await fs.readdir(path);
    let fileCount = 0;
    let subFolderCount = 0;
    let fileTypeInformation = {};
    await Promise.all(files.map(async (name) => {
      const filePath = `${path}/${name}`;
      const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        subFolderCount++;
        await readDirectory(filePath);
      } else {
        fileCount++;
        const fileExtension = `.${name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase()}`;
        fileTypeInformation[fileExtension] =
          (fileTypeInformation[fileExtension] || 0) + 1;
      }
    }));

    result.totalFiles += fileCount;
    result.totalSubFolders += subFolderCount;

    Object.entries(fileTypeInformation).forEach(([fileExtension, fileCount]) => {
      const fileType = new FileTypeInformation(fileExtension, fileCount);
      result.fileTypesInformation.push(fileType);
    });
  }

  readDirectory(folderPath).then(() => callback(null,result));
```

That entire `setTimeout` call can be removed. Those `for` loops are not needed. They assume that the collected file types could have duplicate file extensions, but that is not possible, because they were keys of an object (`fileTypeInformation`). Furthermore, doing a `splice` on an array you are iterating is asking for trouble.

Comment: That solution would not work because it would call callback before full result is built, also as you can see it readDirectory function recursively calls itself, multiple calls to callback would fail test, thanks for your response anyway

Comment: I see. I missed that recursion. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

what did I do wrong? can you help me with that, I pasted your readDriectory function in my code and put import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises'; at the top

Comment: This is straight from the documentation. If you don't run this in a module, then use the corresponding require call. You should already have code that includes `fs`, and it is that line that you should update. But it is more modern practice to configure your file as a module. Look it up.